# An error occurred (Throttling) when calling the DescribeDBClusters operation (reached max retries: 4): Rate exceeded

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to copy multiple file to s3 bucket by using following AWS CLI command

```
aws s3 cp local_dir s3://s3_bucket/dir1/xmldir/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.xml"
```

Here for each file upload an AWS lambda will be getting triggered like wise i configured
after lambda getting trigger it process the file which copied to s3.

The problem here is: out of 360 files 200 only successfully processed for remaining getting the error:

> An error occurred (Throttling) when calling the DescribeDBClusters operation (reached max retries: 4): Rate exceeded

Comment: Seems like you are having a problem with the rate limits of AWS S3 service. Maybe you can slow down your upload process with queues.

https://aws.amazon.com/tr/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-request-limit-avoid-throttling/

Comment: We can't guess what's in your Lambda.